# Rails production - all pictures are broken after new deploy

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, ubuntu-12.04, unicorn

I followed the [Ryan's screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps) and deployed to VPS. So i use Unicorn + nginx + github + Ubuntu 12.04 LTS + capistrano. Also i use i18n to translate application.

I also would like to notice that i use [Carriarewave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) for picture uploading. Carriarewave keeps pictures on VPS locally. When i upload images it works great and uploaded pictures appear.

But each time when i deploy new changes to the server then ALL my pictures become broken. It's really awfull. I tried manually to restart nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

And i tried to restart Unicorn:

```
/etc/init.d/unicorn_Chirch_app restart
```

It doesn't help too.

When i try to open my broken page manually it says:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

When i try to find pictures in console:

```
> Photo.all
> => [#<Photo id: 3, description: nil, created_at: "2013-01-21 11:14:01", updated_at: "2013-01-21 11:14:01", image: "1320700703588.jpg">, #<Photo id: 4, description: nil, created_at: "2013-01-21 11:14:01", updated_at: "2013-01-21 11:14:01", image: "Seasonscape_by_alexiuss.jpg">, #<Photo id: 5, description: nil, created_at: "2013-01-21 11:30:30", updated_at: "2013-01-21 11:30:30", image: "Seasonscape_by_alexiuss.jpg">]
```

As i understand they should exist.

Error from logs:

```
Started GET "/ru/uploads%2Fphoto%2Fimage%2F4%2FSeasonscape_by_alexiuss" for 89.178.205.47 at 2013-01-21 11:31:17 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/ru/uploads%2Fphoto%2Fimage%2F4%2FSeasonscape_by_alexiuss"):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  unicorn (4.5.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.5.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:628:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.5.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.5.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:511:in `maintain_worker_count'
  unicorn (4.5.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:277:in `join'
  unicorn (4.5.0) bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deployer/apps/My_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /home/deployer/apps/My_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

My **config/deploy.rb**

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "my_ip_here", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "My_app"
set :user, "deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:MyName/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. The problem appeared because I didn't change the default folder to keep images. You can find your default folder in `public/uploads`. That means that each `cap deploy` will create a new empty folder which doesn't contain your older files.

To fix this you should create another folder which doesn't live in your application. I choose the easiest way. I created symlinlk.

My steps:

1) On your server go to your app's shared folder (it generated automatically via capistrano). And then create your folder to keep new images:

```
$ mkdir uploads
```

2) Give necessary rights for a created folder:

```
$ sudo chmod 775 uploads
```

3) On your local machine in config/deploy.rb add:

```
task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
  ...
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/uploads"
end
```

4) Then push git and deploy:

```
$ git push
$ cap deploy:symlink
$ cap deploy
```

Now everything works fine.

Comment: Hey, I know, a lot of time have pass, but I have the same problem. And about your steps. I don't  understand, in your first step, why do we need to create folder if it automatically created?

Answer (score 2):

Good one! I've extended your capistrano recipe.

```
# config/recipes/carrierwave.rb

namespace :carrierwave do 
  task :uploads_folder do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/uploads"
    run "#{sudo} chmod 775 #{shared_path}/uploads"
  end
  after 'deploy:setup', 'carrierwave:uploads_folder'

  task :symlink do 
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/uploads"
  end
  after 'deploy', 'carrierwave:symlink'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@ExiRe & @Charlie answer works on Capistrano 2.x. In Capistrano 3.x, command **run** replaced with command **execute**.

So, I solved this with the following steps:

1. Create a rake file in the directory `lib/capistrano/tasks/carrierwave.rake` with the content:

```
namespace :carrierwave do
  task :uploads_folder do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/uploads"
      execute "#{sudo} chmod 775 #{shared_path}/uploads"
    end
  end
  
  task :symlink do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/uploads"
    end
  end
end
```

2. Add the following line at the end of your `Capfile` if it's doesn't have it.
   `Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }`
3. Add these tasks in `config/deploy.rb` with other tasks.

- `after 'deploy:publishing', 'carrierwave:uploads_folder'`
- `after 'deploy:publishing', 'carrierwave:symlink'`

```
namespace :deploy do
  ..
  after 'deploy:publishing', 'carrierwave:uploads_folder'
  after 'deploy:publishing', 'carrierwave:symlink'
  ..
end
```

4. Push git and deploy

Now your uploaded image will remain saved in `shared/uploads` folder after even new deploy.